# Why do we use * in the end of java.sql.* package

Tags: java

I am very confused that why we use a asterisk* in the end of java.sql.* package whereas we dont do this usually ?

Comment: It just means that you are importing all Classes in that package.  It is generally considered good practice to only import what you need, but frankly it doesn't really matter.

Comment: In general, when you use `*` in an import, you import all the classes from the package (e.g. `java.io.*`)

Comment: Don't confuse "import" with "class loading".  All you're doing here is saving keystrokes: ResultSet versus java.sql.ResultSet.  I prefer NOT using the * notation - ever.  A good IDE (e.g. IntelliJ) will insert import statements for you.  Spell them out.

Comment: In regular expressions `*` means to match anything. So in Java when we use it `java.sql.*`. That `*` means every file it can find inside `java.sql`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with java.sql. Your last five words are correct.

Comment: Why is this question being voted down and closed? It's a perfectly legitimate question for someone who's learning Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing `import java.sql.*` you import all classes from the package `java.sql` at once, so that you don't have to import them one by one. It's more convenient to write when you're importing many classes from some package.

For example, instead of:

```
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Connection;
// ...etc.
```

you can just write:

```
import java.sql.*;
```

Note that importing everything in a package can also have a disadvantage: you might be importing classes that you didn't want. For example, the packages `java.util` and `java.sql` both contain a class named `Date`. If you do this:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
```

then, when you use `Date` in your source file, the compiler will complain because it doesn't know if you mean `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`.

Comment: A brief comment: At least MySQL recommends *not to import* `java.sql.*`, but only the needed classes... maybe (or maybe not) other connectors have that same recommendation. It is always a good idea to check the documentation for the connector being used.